# HttpWebRequest: use http 1.0 on connect method

Tags: c#, http, certificate, httpwebrequest

In my program I need to connect with a certificate, I see that Internet explorer, that works,  uses HTTP 1.0 .
I tried to add `req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;` but In log I see:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [XXX] HttpWebRequest#XX - Request: CONNECT server.ext:443 HTTP/1.1
```

and

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [XXX] HttpWebRequest#XX - Request: POST /page.form HTTP/1.0
```

so it uses version 1.0 only for a part of connection...
How can I set the protocol for the connect method?
Thanks,
Antonino

Answer (score 0):

you do not have control over the Proxy Tunneling phase when using HttpWebRequest, so it will always use HTTP/1.1 during the CONNECT phase of the SSL tunneling. Is there any particular reason you want HTTP/1.0 support? If you are using older versions of proxies such as Squid - then I believe there's already an update to Squid to support HTTP/1.1.